# Error installing maatwebsite/excel on laravel 10.48.4

Tags: excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

Im trying to install maatwebsite/excel for a project and the problem that i have is that when i do it installs the 1.1 version which is unsupported instead of the 3.3. Im currently using Laravel Framework 10.48.4 and PHP 8.2 version.

I need to use the 3.3 version because i need to implement in the project excels import. But when i run the command it appears the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

your project did not correctly install maatwebsite/excel library. That is the reason you can not run the php artisan make: import command when this error occurs. First, you can try this install maatwebsite/excel using this command:

composer require maatwebsite/excel --ignore-platform-reqs

This commands your platform to ignore and install it.

Comment: Thanks for commenting but I resolved the problem by going in php.ini and uncommenting the ; in line extension=gd

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).